# Change value on success, but not changing

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I need to change the `var state` on success, but debugging the js code, it doesn't call the success function at all, even though there is success. The state variable remains undefined. I'm not sure why it doesn't change. Looking at the network using firebug, the response is `{"d": 1}`, which is the value the state should have. Any help is appreciated

```
var state;

$.ajax({
        url: "isoServe.asmx/GetStatus",
        type: "GET",        
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            state = msg.d;
        }, 
        error: function() {
            alert("Error" );
        }
    }); 

return state;
```

Comment: This question was asked many-many times. Ajax request is executed asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You should `return` the `state` inside the AJAX Call:

var state;

```
$.ajax({
    url: "isoServe.asmx/GetStatus",
    type: "GET",        
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        state = msg.d;
        return state;
    }, 
    error: function() {
        alert("Error" );
    }
});
```

In your case, the `return` statement fires before the AJAX Response could come! As it says, asynchronous, you need to wait till it gets the response.

---

#### Update:

You cannot have a response for the AJAX call directly, as it is an asynchronous request. Instead, it can invoke another function in the `success` callback, such that the function is triggered and states are set.

Comment: Ehm... Return it to where? You actually return it to nowhere...

Comment: @Regent Looking at the code, it looks like it is a part inside a function.

Comment: Yes, it looks so. So that's why I don't understand why you returned it **inside** success callback function.

Comment: I explained. Please read the answer again!

Comment: I have read it multiple times. Once again: what is the point of `return state;` inside success callback function? It returns value to nowhere. For all that I see the idea is to return value from external function, which has this ajax call.

Comment: It returns the value to the place, where the original return is there in the OP's post. Agree?

Comment: Nope. `state` value will be changed on success, but `return state;` just does nothing (doesn't return value to external function).

Comment: @Regent So do you know how to make the function return it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Hmmm, it will return `undefined`, if it's a function

Comment: @PraveenKumar you suggest [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0o4wa8az/), don't you?

Comment: @user1960836 you should call another function when you will get result from server

Comment: Unless i just miss-understand the point of your answer, your answer is simply wrong. you can't return from the success callback.

Comment: @user1960836 you can use `$.Deferred()` ([fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/0o4wa8az/1/)) or callback function ([fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/0o4wa8az/2/))

Comment: @Regent You get an error here: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) `

Comment: @PraveenKumar it is not an error: there is no such URL in _jsfiddle.net_, and the code is example. Actually that's why there is returning `-1` with comment **// for JSFiddle** in error callback.